# Angular : Variable is undefined

Tags: angular, rest

I have a function that does some operations on a variable that's populated from a service call. My code is something like this.

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.itemservice.getItems().subscribe(data => { this.items = data}
   var d = myfunction(this.items);
}
```

Here my method inside the service.

```
getItems() : Observable<Item[]> {

  let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization','Bearer ' + token );
  return this.http.get(this.url + '/items',{headers: headers}).map(res => <Item[]> res['result']);
```

}

My items is displayed in templates without any issue but i get `this.items` is not defined when the function is called.

Comment: add more code here

Comment: can you show your code for `datafromservice()`?

Comment: Probably because that method doesn't return anything. Probably because it does something asynchronous and you're not dealing with that correctly. Without a [mcve] it's hard to be more specific.

Comment: I add more code to my question. My function returns a number calculated from my items' attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First there are issues in your `ngOnInit`, you're missing a `)` and you should be using `let`, not `var` as `var` will hoist that variable to the top of the class, where `let` will block scope the variable to that function.

Secondly, Angular is async, you should be calling the function you want to use `this.items` with inside of the `subscribe` event of `getItems()`. The way you currently have it, your `myfunction(thisitems)` is firing before the `subscribe()` event. Please see below.

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.itemservice.getItems().subscribe(data => { 
       this.items = data;
       let d = myfunction(this.items);
   });
}
```

Your service should map the response to json, please see below:

```
getItems() : Observable<Item[]> {   
  let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization','Bearer ' + token );
  return this.http.get(this.url + '/items',{headers: headers}).map(res => res.json());
}
```

Also note that Angular 4+ is using HttpClient instead of regular Http. Your code will change to the following in your service

```
getItems() : Observable<Item[]> {   
  let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization','Bearer ' + token );
  return this.http.get<item[]>(this.url + '/items',{headers: headers});

}
```

Comment: I'm using Angular 4+ and your answer worked for me so i'm going to accept it.

Comment: You may want to consider upgrading to HttpClient instead, it's easier to work with as well. Eventually they will move over completely :)

Comment: Actually i'm using HttpClient.

Answer (score -1):

As angular is asyc language and your service

```
(this.itemservice.getItems().subscribe(data => { this.items = data})
```

is executing at same time when your

```
this(var d = myfunction(this.items);)
```

function is called so add this line under the service call

```
var d = myfunction(this.items);
```

for not getting the error